# matplotlib event handling to interact with objects on the canvas

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I'm using [this code](http://matplotlib.org/examples/event_handling/poly_editor.html) to draw a plot of connected points and to drag the points freely on the plot. I just need to change the polygon fill color from Blue to White. Please advise how to do so.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
from matplotlib.artist import Artist
from matplotlib.mlab import dist_point_to_segment

class PolygonInteractor:

    showverts = True
    epsilon = 5  # max pixel distance to count as a vertex hit

    def __init__(self, ax, poly):
        if poly.figure is None:
            raise RuntimeError('You must first add the polygon to a figure or canvas before defining the interactor')
        self.ax = ax
        canvas = poly.figure.canvas
        self.poly = poly

        x, y = zip(*self.poly.xy)
        self.line = Line2D(x, y, marker='o', markerfacecolor='r', animated=True)
        self.ax.add_line(self.line)
        #self._update_line(poly)

        cid = self.poly.add_callback(self.poly_changed)
        self._ind = None # the active vert

        canvas.mpl_connect('draw_event', self.draw_callback)
        canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.button_press_callback)
        canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', self.key_press_callback)
        canvas.mpl_connect('button_release_event', self.button_release_callback)
        canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', self.motion_notify_callback)
        self.canvas = canvas


    def draw_callback(self, event):
        self.background = self.canvas.copy_from_bbox(self.ax.bbox)
        self.ax.draw_artist(self.poly)
        self.ax.draw_artist(self.line)
        self.canvas.blit(self.ax.bbox)

    def poly_changed(self, poly):
        'this method is called whenever the polygon object is called'
        # only copy the artist props to the line (except visibility)
        vis = self.line.get_visible()
        Artist.update_from(self.line, poly)
        self.line.set_visible(vis)  # don't use the poly visibility state


    def get_ind_under_point(self, event):
        'get the index of the vertex under point if within epsilon tolerance'

        # display coords
        xy = np.asarray(self.poly.xy)
        xyt = self.poly.get_transform().transform(xy)
        xt, yt = xyt[:, 0], xyt[:, 1]
        d = np.sqrt((xt-event.x)**2 + (yt-event.y)**2)
        indseq = np.nonzero(np.equal(d, np.amin(d)))[0]
        ind = indseq[0]

        if d[ind]>=self.epsilon:
            ind = None

        return ind

    def button_press_callback(self, event):
        'whenever a mouse button is pressed'
        if not self.showverts: return
        if event.inaxes==None: return
        if event.button != 1: return
        self._ind = self.get_ind_under_point(event)

    def button_release_callback(self, event):
        'whenever a mouse button is released'
        if not self.showverts: return
        if event.button != 1: return
        self._ind = None

    def key_press_callback(self, event):
        'whenever a key is pressed'
        if not event.inaxes: return
        if event.key=='t':
            self.showverts = not self.showverts
            self.line.set_visible(self.showverts)
            if not self.showverts: self._ind = None
        elif event.key=='d':
            ind = self.get_ind_under_point(event)
            if ind is not None:
                self.poly.xy = [tup for i,tup in enumerate(self.poly.xy) if i!=ind]
                self.line.set_data(zip(*self.poly.xy))
        elif event.key=='i':
            xys = self.poly.get_transform().transform(self.poly.xy)
            p = event.x, event.y # display coords
            for i in range(len(xys)-1):
                s0 = xys[i]
                s1 = xys[i+1]
                d = dist_point_to_segment(p, s0, s1)
                if d<=self.epsilon:
                    self.poly.xy = np.array(
                        list(self.poly.xy[:i]) +
                        [(event.xdata, event.ydata)] +
                        list(self.poly.xy[i:]))
                    self.line.set_data(zip(*self.poly.xy))
                    break


        self.canvas.draw()

    def motion_notify_callback(self, event):
        'on mouse movement'
        if not self.showverts: return
        if self._ind is None: return
        if event.inaxes is None: return
        if event.button != 1: return
        x,y = event.xdata, event.ydata

        self.poly.xy[self._ind] = x,y
        self.line.set_data(zip(*self.poly.xy))

        self.canvas.restore_region(self.background)
        self.ax.draw_artist(self.poly)
        self.ax.draw_artist(self.line)
        self.canvas.blit(self.ax.bbox)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from matplotlib.patches import Polygon

    theta = np.arange(0, 2*np.pi, 0.1)
    r = 1.5

    xs = r*np.cos(theta)
    ys = r*np.sin(theta)

    poly = Polygon(list(zip(xs, ys)), animated=True)

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.add_patch(poly)
    p = PolygonInteractor(ax, poly)

    #ax.add_line(p.line)
    ax.set_title('Click and drag a point to move it')
    ax.set_xlim((-2,2))
    ax.set_ylim((-2,2))
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `facecolor='white'` to fill the Polygon with white:

```
poly = Polygon(list(zip(xs, ys)), animated=True, facecolor='white')
```

or use `fill=False` to leave the interior transparent.

```
poly = Polygon(list(zip(xs, ys)), animated=True, fill=False)
```